# RunAnalyticsReport returning incorrect rows

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, rightnow-crm

I have a problem with the RightNow SOAP API, specifically requesting a RunAnalyticsReport, the code is below. The export works when I set the report to return a fixed period, e.g. 4 or 6 hours. When I set the report to require a start date (AlertClosedAfter in this case), it timed out. Then I re-ran it after disabling the start date requirement and it only returns the rows that are created after the time out, no matter if I set any filters or not (I'm pretty sure my filter is wrong, so if you can help me with that it would be perfect). So now every time I run it it only returns the rows since the time out. Do you guys have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:v1="urn:messages.ws.rightnow.com/v1_2"
xmlns:v11="urn:base.ws.rightnow.com/v1_2"
xmlns:ns2="urn:objects.ws.rightnow.com/v1_2"
xmlns:ns3="urn:generic.ws.rightnow.com/v1_2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:ns4="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<v1:ClientInfoHeader>
<v1:AppID>Create</v1:AppID>
</v1:ClientInfoHeader>
<ns4:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
<UsernameToken xsi:type="ns4:UsernameToken">
<Username>username</Username>
<Password>password</Password>
</UsernameToken>
</ns4:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<n0:GetResponse xmlns:n0="urn:messages.ws.rightnow.com/v1_2" xmlns:n2="urn:base.ws.rightnow.com/v1_2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:n1=
"urn:objects.ws.rightnow.com/v1_2">
<n0:RNObjectsResult>
<n0 :RNObjects xsi:type="n1:AnalyticsReport">
<n2:ID id="103151"></n2:ID>                 
<n1:Filters xsi:type="n1:AnalyticsReportFilter">
<n1:Name>AlertsClosedAfter</n1:Name>
<n1:Operator>
<n2:ID id="6"></n2:ID>
<n2:Name>></n2:Name>
</n1:Operator>
<n1:Values>29/01/2015 13:40</n1:Values>
<n1:Attributes>
<n1:Editable>true</n1:Editable>
<n1:Required>false</n1:Required>
</n1:Attributes>
<n1:DataType>
<n2:ID id="4"></n2:ID>
<n2:Name>DATETIME</n2:Name>
</n1:DataType>
<n1:Prompt>AlertsClosedAfter</n1:Prompt>
</n1:Filters>
<n1:Filters xsi:type="n1:AnalyticsReportFilter">
<n1:Name>Lead Rejection Reason</n1:Name>
<n1:Operator>
<n2:ID id="1"></n2:ID>
<n2:Name>=</n2:Name>
</n1:Operator>
<n1:Values>~any~</n1:Values>
<n1:Attributes>
<n1:Editable>true</n1:Editable>
<n1:Required>false</n1:Required>
</n1:Attributes>
<n1:DataType>
<n2:ID id="1"></n2:ID>
<n2:Name>MENU</n2:Name>
</n1:DataType>
<n1:Prompt>Lead Rejection Reason</n1:Prompt>
</n1:Filters>
</n0:RNObjects>
</n0:RNObjectsResult>
</n0:GetResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: By "it timed out", do you mean that the API returned a response that the report ran for too long?  Now, despite answers to change the filter, you only get records created after that time out occurred?  I think @richard morgan is correct about your date issue, but it also sounds like the report may have been switched to deferred execution or to report off of the "report database", which might be behind your operational database.  You can check the report settings in the console under "Options/More options" when editing your report.

Comment: Yes, I'm using SoapUI to test it and it return that it ran too long. The filter is irrelevant at this point because I've tried removing it and it and the rows it return were still the ones created after the original time out. I will investigate the deferred execution, I hope that is it. Thank you!

Comment: That didn't seem to work, I'm still getting the same response. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Does the report queue in the agent console when you run without setting filters?  Also, you are aware that reports only return 10000 records per page, right?  Are you looking at those first 10k records and assuming that the newer ones should be there?  Do you get different results if you paginate through the report?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the format for dates is:

```
<year-month-day>T<24 hour time>Z
```

For example:

```
2015-01-29T13:40:00Z
```

Change your AlertsClosedAfter filter value to something like that.

Comment: I've tried this, could be helpful in the future, but now there's a problem even without the filters.